# Mongo DB collection fields schema best practice

Tags: php, collections, mongodb, schema-design

I would like to know how does i have to set up my collections schemas?

I mean first i need ,for example, a user object (username,email,password), then i need a field to make users confirm registration so need i to insert all fields when inserting users (username,email,password,confirm=0)

or

better to create confirm field only when user goes to confirm his registration account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `confirm` field tells you that it's `0`, so both seem to be fine, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: so if field does not exist and i anyway try to select that it will return error as for mysql fields? anyway i need to try that :P thx!

Comment: actually you rarely retrieve a single field with mongo.. you retrieve the whole document, and then you'll have a missing confirm field. `isset` vs `== 0`.

Comment: uhmmm :) ... not totally agree, since there is the option to specify which field/fields to retrieve i think is important (as for mySQL) specify only fields that i need to return back don't you think? I'm newbie on mongo, this is just a new question :)

Comment: yes, I'm just saying it rarely used. actually in this case you don't need to retrieve any fields (just the `_id`) if you search for a document with `confirm: true`.